# How do I properly say “Let X be a Y” in the mathematical setting?

Tags: conjugaison, mathématiques, subjonctif

In English I would say: "Let G be a locally compact group."

In French I think it would go something like: "Soit G être d'un groupe localement compact."

But I don't think I have conjugated the verb *être* properly.

Can someone correct me?

---

**Update**:  I found an example of this in literature, appearing as: “Soit G un groupe localement compact.”

So does the phrase “Soit G …” mean something along the lines of “Let G be that which is …”?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, “*soit*” is the *subjonctif présent* 3<sup>rd</sup> person singular of “être”.

The correct form is indeed:

> Soit *G* un groupe localement compact […]

When the subject is plural, e.g. “Let *G* and *H* be locally compact groups”, you can use either “Soient” (*subjonctif présent*, 3<sup>rd</sup> person plural) or “Soit”, as the construction became idiomatic.

> Soient *G* et *H* des groupes localement compacts […]
>
> Soit *G* et *H* des groupes localement compacts […]

Comment: So you have to pluralize 'compacts' to match up with the pluralization of 'groupes'?

Comment: Yes, as with every adjective in French.