# Attaching “gauche” (or “droite”) to a noun

Tags: noms, mathématiques

I'm trying to translate the following English mathematical sentence into French.

''*Let G be a locally compact group, where u is the left Haar measure on G.*''

For the first part, it has already been answered here:

[How do I properly say “Let X be a Y” in the mathematical setting?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/how-do-i-properly-say-let-x-be-a-y-in-the-mathematical-setting/9561#9561)

I should begin with ''*Soit G un groupe localement compact,*''

as for the rest, I could say ''*et soit u la mesure de Haar surs G.*'', but would this form a run-on sentence, or am I even saying what I mean to?

And finally, since ''*gauche*'' is the French word for ''*left*'', where do I insert it to modify my statement correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je traduirais comme ceci:

> Soit G un groupe localement compact où u est la mesure de Haar à gauche sur G.

Comment: Merci. :) ------